# Can you get flat response with Linkwitz-Riley cross-over?

Tags: filters

Many pictures display that the [Linkwitz-Riley](http://sound.westhost.com/p09_fig2.gif) has $-6\textrm{ dB}$ dips at the cross-over frequencies.

[image]

Are these fixed or can these made flat?

Comment: Adding to a flat response it nearly pointless in cross over design. It says only little about the resulting response of the speaker combination, because each of the speakers comes with an individual response that will change things enough to mess with the combined response. If you want to create a excellent crossover, you need to design it with the speakers and cabinets taken into account and the result will almost certainly not be one that adds up to a flat response on paper.

Comment: This plot is not the sum, but the individual filters! The sum doesn't have 6dB dips.

Answer (score 1):

Linkwitz Riley filters always have  -6 dB at the cut off frequency. The whole idea of a cross over is to split the signal into multiple bands. The advantage of a Linkwitz Riley is that it adds to be flat (at least in amplitude). So each the highpass and the low pass have -6 dB at the crossover, but the sum of both is flat.

Comment: So do the low and high pass sum so that it results in a flat response, rather than -6dB?

Comment: Linkwitz-Riley add to an all-pass filter.  an APF is flat in magnitude.  it's group delay is not flat.

Comment: Each individual band will have the magnitude response plotted.  -6dB is a linear gain (attenuation?) of 0.5, so adding two 0.5s at the crossover frequencies gives 1.0 (assuming phase alignment!).

Answer (score 1):

suppose it's an LR4.  the low-end crossover is two 2nd-order Butterworth LPFs in cascade.  the high-end crossover is two 2nd-order Butterworth HPFs in cascade.  it turns out that adding the two 4th-order transfer functions gives you a 4th-order all-pass filter (APF).  so the overall gain is flat.

the -3 dB point of a single 2nd-order Butterworth is also where the phase shift is 90°.  so two in cascade is -6 dB and -180°.  at the crossover point, both the LPF and HPF are at -6 dB and -180°, so they both have linear gain of $-\frac12$ and are in phase.  so they add to $-1$.  at low frequencies they are close to 0° phase shift and at high frequencies they are close to 360° phase shift.